Insert key is 'on' by default on startup. How to disable this?
At some point, my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (running X11) started having the insert key 'on' (my keyboard has a light to indicate when the insert key is toggled on) when the machine starts up. Why has it started doing this and what can I do to make it stop?
I've never intentionally used the insert key and I would never intentionally tell the system to toggle it on at startup.
Thanks.

Is this a dual boot setup?

No. I have a Windows VM on the Ubuntu, but no dual boot and the VM is not activated at startup.

updated bios recently?

When Ubuntu is ready to start have you tried hitting esc and getting into the grub menu?

Nope, 2018 bios version.

I have been in the grub menu before. What should I being doing there?

is this not a setting in BIOS same as setting Num Lock etc on/off?

Not that I can find. There is a Num Lock setting, but nothing regarding Insert.
